# Case: Too many arguments error for switch in C shell

Tags: shell, unix, csh

Yes, I am using csh. No, I do not have a choice about it.

I am currently trying to calculate yesterday's date using today's date.
However the switch I am using to try to set the "day" number when today is the first of the month is throwing the error `Case: Too many arguments`
Here is my code snippet:

```
#!/bin/csh


set todaysMonth = `date '+%m'`
set todaysDay = `date '+%d'`
set todaysYear = `date '+%Y'`
set yestMonth
set yestDay
set yestYear

set todaysMonth = 1
set todaysDay = 1

if ($todaysDay == 1) then
   switch ($todaysMonth)
     case 5:
     case 7:
     case 10:
     case 12: set yestDay = 30
              breaksw
     case 1:
     case 2:
     case 4:
     case 6:
     case 8:
     case 9:
     case 11: set yestDay = 31
              breaksw

     case 3:  # don't care about leap year right now
              echo "Setting yestDay to 28"
              set yestDay = 28
              breaksw
     default: echo "Failied to set yestDay"
   endsw

echo "Today:" $todaysDay
echo "Yesterday:" $yestDay
endif
```

Output: `Case: Too many arguments`

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not:

```
case <arg>: <command>
```

it's:

```
case <arg>:
   <command>
```

The man page does show this, but it's not telling you it will error if you don't.

You need to do this on the 4 lines.

And you need an `endif`.

Comment: I tried a simple example with `case arg: <command>` on one line, and csh didn't complain, but the code didn't work correctly. I've found csh's parser to be less than consistent (one reason I abandoned it some time ago).

Comment: Indeed, csh's parser being hand-built is the core of the "why csh is unsuitable for script development" argument made at https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

Comment: That was it! You can't put the command on the same line as the case.  Never would have guessed that! Thank you.